# Substring of a wikimedia variable

Tags: mediawiki

I have a wiki template that expects a variable named param1. The values for param1 will be of the form XYZ-ABCDEFG. I know that I can use {{{param1}}} and it will then substitute XYZ-ABCDEFG into the wiki page. However, I would like to save the XYZ part (and I know it is always 3 letter long) and save that in a variable. I tried to do

```
{{#vardefineecho:first_part|{{#invoke:String|sub|:{{{param1}}}|1|3}} }}
```

This displays

```
{{#invoke:String|sub|:{{{param1}}}|1|3}}
```

on the page.

How can I get the first part of param1?

Comment: Did you install the [Scribunto](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto) extension?

Comment: @Tgr It's a corp wiki. How can I tell if it's installed?

Comment: Check Special:Version.

Comment: Not installed, and I can't install it

Comment: `#invoke` is not available then. You can use [`{{padleft:{{{param1|}}}|3}}`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Formatting) instead which is a built-in.